# Half of the pathways I try to download don't have node annotations

Tags: cytoscape

I am downloading pathways from WikiPathways to visualise protein expression data. Some pathways download fine, however some (including WP2572, WP51, WP306) do not have node annotations. I am not doing anything differently when downloading them, is anybody able to suggest a solution?

[Screen capture of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp4an.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us which version of Cytoscape and which version of the wikipathways app you are using?  I just imported WP2572 and it looks fine on my machine.  You may also want to make sure that the style sheet has the correct mapping -- it should be a passthrough mapping from "name".

-- scooter

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am using v3.8.2 of cytoscape and wikipathways 3.3.7, and the  style sheet settings all seem to be correct.